# Spotify Web API in C# Authorization

Tags: c#, spotify

I am working with the Spotify API, specifically the authorisation part https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization-guide/ but when I do the following bit of code, it returns a web page to the Spotify Login screen; which is mentioned in that documentation.

However, I am wondering, how can I display that Spotify Login screen in a Windows Application e.g. Windows Forms or WPF application; then proceed onto getting to the redirect_uri with the authorization code I require to pass onto to get an access token?

```
var request = "https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize/?" +
  "client_id=" + clientId +
  "&response_type=code" +
  "&redirect_uri=" + redirectUri +
  "&scope=" + scope;

HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

var httpResponse = await client.GetAsync(request);
var content = await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Comment: Not related to your current issue, but [you're using HttpClient wrong and it's destabilizing your software](https://www.aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/).

Comment: @mason thanks for the response, I usually have a single instance of the HttpClient as a global variable, but for demonstration purposes; just initialised it in the code I added here.

Comment: You should use https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization-guide/#client-credentials-flow

Comment: @nredko thanks mate, that seems to be working!